# Is it ok to nest Firebase listeners?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I'm using React&Redux + Firebase, and I have been wondering whether it is ok to nest event listeners. I'm copying a snippet below to show what I mean. My concern is that whenever a new item is added to accountTypes, the first listener will also trigger the second, when this may be unnecessary, right? I feel I'm missing something here very important

```
export const fetchAccounts = (companyId) => {
return dispatch => {

    return firebaseDB.ref(`company/${companyId}/accountTypes`).on('value', snapshot => {

        let accountTypes = snapshot.val();

        if(accountTypes) {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_ACCOUNT_TYPES,
                payload: accountTypes,
            });

            return firebaseDB.ref(`company/${companyId}/accounts`).on('value', snapshot => {
                let accounts = snapshot.val()

                return dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_ACCOUNTS,
                    payload: accounts,
                });
            })

        }

        return;
    });
}
```

};

Thank you for letting me pick your brains!

Comment: It seems like you just want to get data once, and not listen for updates indefinitely.  If that's the case, you should just be using once() instead of on().

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson , in my case, I do want to listen to both, there are other components of my app that need real-time updates. My concern is whether it is ok to have nested listeners as above. Thank you in advance

Comment: It's OK if it meets the needs of your app, but I can't tell what those needs are.  I'm troubled by the fact that your code never removes the listeners, which is an important part of not wasting your users' bandwidth and keeping your billing under control.  Maybe you should edit the question to explain what you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, thank for your quick reply, you also brought up another question that has been puzzling me: If  real time updates are needed for component A but component B doesn't need real time updates. Should the best design pattern be:  Use listeners when mounting componentA and turn them off when unmounting A. Then for component B, just do a one time read using 'once'. Does this match your logic? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Sure, if that meets your needs.  Since you haven't really said what you're trying to accomplish, I can't really say if it's the right thing to do.  But you should always remove listeners when they're no longer needed, and only access data once if that's all you need.